# Acces JSON Object in google cloud functions

Tags: node.js, json, function, parsing, cloud

i'm trying to parse a response in a google cloud function.
The text response is: 
`{"data":{"Object_Create":{"id":107}}}` and stored in var body.

i convert it this way:
`var obj= JSON.parse(body)`

Then i try to access the object:
`var Object_Create= obj.data.Object_Create`

and works.

The problem is when i try to get the id field with:
`var id= obj.data.Object_Create.id`
because it returns `ReferenceError: id is not defined`

I tried the same code from an online JS editor and it's working without any problems so it seems related to the cloud platform.
Did someone experienced the same problem?

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to parse that response, as it is a Javascript object, which means there is no extra processing necessary.

If you do try to parse it, it should throw a syntax error

```
SyntaxError: Unexpected token o in JSON at position 1
```

you can just access it by

```
console.log(body.data.Object_Create.id)
```

I imagine you actually want to use that key however, so you could

```
const { Object_Create } = body.data

console.log(Object_Create.id)
```

Comment: hei, thanks for the reply, but i don't think it's the right solution. I mean, if i try to access this without convert it in a json object it thorwas a execpcion. The parsgin is correct, since it allows me to access ''Object_Create'', the problem is that i cannot access to the nested field ''id''

Comment: thanks, but you are creating the object as a JSON object, i get it as a String, and need to parse it. The parsing goes well, as i used it in other platforms, and can access to data.Object_create, the problem is that if i put .id at the end to get the number, it says ''undefined''. Anyway i solved it with a dirty workaround, i pass the data.Object_Create to a regex function and extract the contained number, not the best solution but working

Comment: `var obj=JSON.parse(body).data;`

`console.log(obj.Object_Create);`    this is working, `console.log(obj.Object_Create.id)`  this not

Comment: Well that's not what your question states. I don't see any quotes around those brackets...

Comment: sorry for wasting your time, i thought that ''The text response is:'' and ''i convert it this way: var obj= JSON.parse(body)

Then i try to access the object: var Object_Create= obj.data.Object_Create

and works.'' was enough.  Thank you anyway for your effort!